# UIButton being added to tableView a couple of times

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a UIButton subclass called Checkbox, and I add it to the cells content view when the cellForRowAtIndex method is called.

I have a problem though. The button is added to the cell a few times. How can I prevent this?

Here is my code:

RootViewController:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UILabel *lab, *dlabl, *cornerLabel;
    CheckBox *btn =  (CheckBox *)[_checkboxArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        //I added this code:
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 3; // 0 means no max.


        UIImageView* img = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient7.png"]] autorelease];
        [cell setBackgroundView:img];

        lab = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 18, cell.contentView.frame.size.width-15, 22)] autorelease];
        [lab setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [lab setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [lab setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
        [lab setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
        [lab setTag:kTEXT_LABEL_TAG];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lab];

        dlabl = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 54, cell.contentView.frame.size.width- 1, 22)] autorelease];
        [dlabl setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.80 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0]];
        [dlabl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
       // [dlabl setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
        [dlabl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
        [dlabl setTag:kDETAIL_TEXT_LABEL_TAG];
        [dlabl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[lab font].pointSize - 3]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:dlabl];

        cornerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.size.width - 40, 19, 40, 20)] autorelease];
        [cornerLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        //[cornerLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
        [cornerLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
        [cornerLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cornerLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
        [cornerLabel setTag:kCORNER_TEXT_LABEL_TAG];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cornerLabel];
        [cornerLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
    }
    else {
        lab = (UILabel *)[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:kTEXT_LABEL_TAG];
        dlabl = (UILabel *)[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:kDETAIL_TEXT_LABEL_TAG];
        cornerLabel = (UILabel *)[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:kCORNER_TEXT_LABEL_TAG];
    }
    NSDictionary *dict = [_cellTextArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    lab.text = [dict objectForKey:@"textLabel"];
    dlabl.text = [dict objectForKey:@"detailTextLabel"];
    cornerLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"cornerLabel"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
    return cell;
}
```

CheckBox.m

```
- (void)checkImages {
    NSUInteger tag = [self tag];
    BOOL val = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", tag]];
    if (val == YES) {
        [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-pressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", tag]];
    }
    else if (val == NO) {
        [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", tag]];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([[[[event allTouches] anyObject] view] tag] == [self tag]) {
        [self checkImages];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only add your button, when the cell is created, i.e. when dequeueing a reusable cell fails.

Comment: No, you want to add your button when you create a new cell, so it would be in the `if (cell == nil)` block. In the `else` case, you could retrieve the existing button and update its state (checked/unchecked).

Comment: Im quite unsure on what I need to do, would you mind telling me what code needs to go where. When I add the btn as a subview in the if (cell == nil) statement, every however many cells have the same button.

Comment: So what? Same goes for the labels (lab, dlabl, cornerLabel). Look at the code you have for those, try to understand it and apply it to the buttons. It's the same principle.

Comment: wont the tag be a wrong way to compare as the tag is used in NSUserDefaults?